# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader - RestEasy / Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, resteasy

I don't know what to do to fix it. When accessing `localhost:8080/pets/findByStatusLocal` is returning the following error.

**Error**

Error id 9175b683-f00f-4a8d-9246-a30eb0f8865f-5, javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type interface java.util.List

**Pet.java**

```
package org.test;

public class Pet {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Pet() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public Pet(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
org.test.PetService/mp-rest/url=https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/
org.test.PetService/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton
```

**PetService.java**

```
package org.test;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@Path("/pet")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface PetService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("findByStatus")
    public List<Pet> findByStatus(@QueryParam("status") String status);

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("findByStatus")
  
  public CompletionStage<List<Pet>> findByStatusAsync(@QueryParam("status") String status);
}
```

**PetResource.java**

```
package org.test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;

@Path("/pets")
public class PetResource {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    PetService petService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("findByStatusLocal")
    public List<Pet> methodname(@QueryParam("status") String status) {
        return petService.findByStatus(status);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("findByStatusLocalAsync")
    public CompletionStage<List<Pet>> async(@QueryParam("status") String status) {
        return petService.findByStatusAsync(status);
    }
    
}
```

Is it an error in the source code or could it be in the project configuration?
Thank you very much

*** I made the correction - pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What quarkus extensions are you using?

Comment: @geoand I'm using quarkus-arc, quarkus-resteasy-reactive and quarkus-rest-client... tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` to write (and read) JSON object. Alternatively, you can also use the `-jsonb` extension. However, I highly recommend Jackson in this case as it offers many more features.

So, in your `pom.xml` file, add:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do we need resteasy-reactive-jackson when resteasy-jackson is used? resteasy-classic and resteasy-reactive is not compatible to each other.

Comment: We highly recommend switching to RESTEasy Reactive (even for blocking code) as it has more features, and is more deeply integrated in Quarkus.

Comment: I know that quarkus is pushing its user to Resteasy Reactive but I simply dont want it right now. I think it is not matured enough. There were some issues with ContextResolver and ObjectMapper in combination with Resteasy Reactive and maintainers were somewhat cautious to solve the issues. Both are JAX-RS implementations so both should work. The only thing which should be different are features on top of the JAX/Jakarta-RS API (and the implementation of course, resteasy reactive is faster I would presume).